# Wordpress Subdomain - Cloned, New or same Database

Tags: database, wordpress, subdomain, multisite

I'm working with a company that has gone in a new direction since it was founded and is looking to create a separate website for its core services vs. new offerings. I understand the basic SEO/Domain Authority implications of creating a new vs. subdomain, and have opted to go the subdomain route.

This is an existing, single site installation of wordpress. I would like to mimic the styling of the existing site while maintaining some flexibility to make independent changes, **but the most important consideration is not messing up the existing live website.**

How would you recommend going about this? What are the trade-offs?

**As I understand, my options are:**

1. New subdomain from Cpanel, new WP database + template

   - Pros: Easy initial setup, flexibility of separate domain
   - Cons: More development work, long term management
2. New subdomain from Cpanel, clone and migrate existing database/template and modify content

   - Pros: Only have to change out content
   - Cons: Bulky, more initial work, long term management
3. New subdomain, same database as existing site

   - Pros: Easier to manage long term, consistent styling
   - Cons: More risky re: making accidental changes to original site
4. Enable Wordpress multi-site (I don't know much about this)

   - Pros: Easy setup
   - Cons: template complications, could create issues for existing site.

Am I correct in assuming that making changes to a sub-domain with a *separate* database will have absolutely no impact on the existing primary domain/database, barring some catastrophic FTP mistake, etc.?

I have a complete backup of the existing WP database and will backup the site as soon as I get FTP access.

Many thanks! 
Zane

Answer (score 0):

First, I would ask what these two sites' relationship is now and will become in the future. Are they two-sides of the same coin? Like SE and its various brethren? Or are they gmail and project fi? Two different things that happen to be owned and operated by the same people?

I would propose the following options based on how you answer:

1) New subdomain in Cpanel, fresh WP install (database + files)

- Pro: Clean slate, no bloat from the legacy site.
- Con: Lots of work to rebuild anything needed from the old site. You get the privilege of managing two sites long-term.

1.5) New subdomain in Cpanel, fresh WP install, copy some theme files and transfer some of the content/settings from the old site using import/export functionality.

- Pro: Semi-Clean slate. Not as much dev work as option 1.
- Con: Some of the bloat from the legacy site will still follow you around. You get the privilege of managing two sites long-term.

2) New subdomain in Cpanel, duplicate old site as starting point.

- Pro: Less work, already have a starting point.
- Con: Bloat and problems from the legacy site carry over. You get the privilege of managing two sites long-term.

3) New subdomain, same database

- I'm gonna strike this option, it sounds like you'll get all of the problems of a multisite with none of the benefits.

4) WordPress Multisite

- Pro: Less work, both now and in long-term management.
- Con: Breaking changes can take down the whole network.

If your two sites are two-peas in a pod, or even just remotely related, I would recommend Multisite, option 4. (From your description, this is the option I would choose. I'll expound on how I would use multisite below.) If these two sites are two different things headed in different directions, then go ahead and split them, using options 1, 2, or 1.5, depending on the tradeoff you decide for mitigating dev work and not weighing down the new site with things from the old site it won't need.

---

**How to use option 4**

First, just enable multisite on your current WP installation.

After that, give any users from the old site whatever access they need to the new site.

Now, to leverage common-theming with slight differences you can set up your template files like so: Make your current theme the parent theme; then make two child themes splitting off of that; each site will use one of the child themes. Any modifications to the theme should be done in that site's child theme. Any common features should be kept by the parent theme.

Network activate plugins that both site's need, activate other plugins ad hoc as needed.

And there you go! Now all your management and development work can go to both sites.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed, thoughtful response. I could not have asked for more! The websites are for the same company, same name, just an old line of work vs. new directions. I like everything about the idea of the multisite except the risk of screwing up the live site. I suppose I could set up a testing directory and experiment from there, but that's another layer of hassle vs. setting up a new/cloned database.

Answer (score 0):

Based on further research regarding multiple installations vs multisite, I have decided to go with a separate wordpress installation for the subdomain site.

I quote some of the key reasons:

"...it is easier to go from separate installations to Multisite than the other way around."

"Whilst it is possible to have Wordpress Multisite set-up to run these 3 separate sites, it's probably more work than it's worth if you're not very comfortable with Wordpress Multisite yet"

Plugin/Theme compatibility was another concern

Accidental changes to the live site was as well.

Here were a few articles that helped me make a decision based on Kallmanation's response:

https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/why-you-should-not-use-wordpress-multisite.html

https://www.narga.net/wordpress-multisite-versus-multiple-wordpress-installations/